# Silverstripe Multiple Errors on forms

Tags: forms, silverstripe

I am trying to figure out how to add more than one error message to a form field.  Here is the logic I am using currently inside the doFormAction method:

```
$errors = $validation->ValidateInput($data);
foreach($errors as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($value)){
        $errorMessages = "<ul>";
        foreach($value as $errorMessage){
            $errorMessages = $errorMessages . "<li>" . $errorMessage . "</li>"
        }
        $errorMessages = $errorMessages . "</ul>";
        $form->AddErrorMessage($key, $errorMessages, 'bad');
    }
}
```

The above print out will not actually print out the list for me, it will html encode the characters before they get printed out on the page.  If I try to use something like this:

```
$form->AddErrorMessage("Field1", "First Error", 'bad');
$form->AddErrorMessage("Field1", "Second Error", 'bad');
```

I will only see the last error message.  Is there a way with silverstripe forms to produce multiple error messages on a single field?

EDIT:
Here is the function from silverstripe:

```
public function addErrorMessage($fieldName, $message, $messageType, $escapeHtml = true) {
    Session::add_to_array("FormInfo.{$this->FormName()}.errors",  array(
       'fieldName' => $fieldName,
       'message' => $escapeHtml ? Convert::raw2xml($message) : $message,
       'messageType' => $messageType,
    ));
}
```

Meaning that when I add the error message for the second time, it over writes the first one as it uses the same name.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `AddErrorMessage` is supposed to add up to one error per field. Even when having multiple rules per field, I've never added more than one error message, because it might be (a) confusing for the user and (b) fixing one problem might fix others as well.

I'd rather use client-side validation (http://parsleyjs.org, https://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/,...), which is made for rapid feedback. I will then check on the server-side again, but the vast majority of issues has then been fixed on the client-side already; thus I'm not too worried if it's a little more tedious for the rare use case.

If you still want to change it, take a look at http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Form.html#567-581 — you should be able to overwrite / write your own implementation covering multiple errors per field, but I'm not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: FYI, it does look like it [adds multiple error's at least to the session](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Form.html#567-581) for an individual field though I think you are right, I believe somewhere else restricts the errors that are displayed.

Comment: Right, I totally overlooked the `add_to_array` and thought it just set it for the key `"FormInfo.{$this->FormName()}.errors"`

Comment: I will have front end validation, right now I am building purely back end.  And I am working towards having my website fully functional without the javascript as I don't see it necessary as having.   As such, I want to tell the user in one go all the mistakes they have made.  Here is a random example I just made up, they enter a password of 123abc.  I want to return back to them saying, hey you never entered a special character, hey you never entered a capital letter, hey your password is not at least 8 characters, etc...  There seems to be no way to do that on 1 field.

Comment: What I have done right now is appended all the errors with a comma and sent it as a single error, but that seems as such a poor solution.  That function creates an array based on Field Names, so when I use the same field name again, it will over write the first one.

Comment: @Bagzli, I will have a look at the rest of the code for showing errors and back to you with (hopefully) a solution :)

Comment: @Turnerj Thank you!  I had another idea, and that is to overwrite that function and remove the convert to raw portion.  The idea here is that then I can print out an HTML list in a variable from the backend, and then when it passes on the front end, I can render it as HTML, as currently if I were to try and do, the <li> tags would get converted into % and it would print out <li> on the screen for user to see.  Unless there is another way I can decode that from the template?

Comment: OK, the issue why only one error appears is due to the [`setupFormErrors`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Form.html#264-294) function on the `Form` class and the [`setError`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-FormField.html#650-665) function on the `FormField` class. If your form is an extension of the `Form` class, you can override this behaviour. Have a bit of a play around and if you run into issues, create a new question (as it will deviate a bit from this question)